# ERROR: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA cannot be executed from a function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, materialized-view, postgresql-15

I need to execute `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA` from a function/procedure but I'm getting `ERROR:  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA cannot be executed from a function`.

There is any workaround for this apart from making a function return the creation query text and copy paste it to execute it?

Seems really silly but I suppose there is a good reason behind it... Anyway, any workaround for this limitation?

I'm running postgresql 15.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™. Why do you think you **need** to do that from a function?

Comment: Maybe... I want to automate the creation of some materialized views. The source tables have hundreds of columns, each table needs 6 materialized views and each column needs a different aggregation function (AVG or MODE, MIN or BOOL_AND, MAX or BOOL_OR...) on the materialized view. The aggregation functions needed for each column are determined by info stored on other tables. We are talking about some thousands of lines that I would really like to avoid to write by hand, so I was creating a plpgsql function/procedure to automate this and future tables.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `WITH NO DATA` and refresh them separately.

Comment: Why not use a procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A procedure returns the same error. `WITH NO DATA` it's a workaround that does the job even if you have to populate it manually later.

Comment: Using a procedure works for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/380UI4fO

Comment: Weird. I retried right now with a procedure. `CALL my_creation_procedure()` returns: `ERROR:  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA cannot be executed from a function`. Could it be because I'm building the query text dynamically, store it in a variable and then `EXECUTE query_text`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to ensure atomicity and consistency of operations. As stated in the [source code comment](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ebd551f586a801dee426e49ba72fb213e8013890/src/backend/access/transam/xact.c#L3464), some statements

> must not run inside   a transaction block, typically because they have non-rollback-able side effects or do internal commits. [...] issue an error if we appear to be running inside a user-defined function (which could issue more commands and possibly cause a failure after the statement completes).

Since `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA` does at least two things: creates a table, then populates it with data, it's possible that it has an internal commit, hence the error.